# Code splitting application sections via dynamic imports

Tags: reactjs, webpack, code-splitting, dynamic-import

I'm trying to split my application into `chunks` using `dynamic imports`. As far as I've seen, I'm only able to use `dynamic import` for each component, but I'd like to split separate application sections into `chunks`:

- Product section (multiple pages, stores, utils, etc.)
- User section (multiple pages, stores, utils, etc.)

So if user access any route from product section, e.g. /product/:id, product.chunk.js would be loaded.

I couldn't find any examples of this so I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: You're using `react-router`, right?

Comment: I'm planning to use mobx-state-router and implement my own module resolving via routing but I'm stuck with dynamic import resolution of multiple files (whole modules in my case).

Comment: Ah crap... Code splitting with [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting) is freaking easy

Comment: One way that just came up to my mind is to have root index file inside every module which would export everything within that module (and i would dynamically import only that file), but some kind of wildcard solution would be much appreciated in case I forget to add new files to that index.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if `mobx-state-router` supports it, but what you really want here is nested routing. Maybe this will help you find a solution..

eg

main router

```
const Products = React.lazy(() => import('./products'));
const Users = React.lazy(() => import('./users'));
...
<Route path="/products" component={Products} />
<Route path="/users" component={Users} />
```

Then each section has it's own internal router..

products router (in products.jsx)

```
import ProductList from "./product-list";
import Product from "./product";

const ProductsAdmin = React.lazy(() => import('./products-admin'));

<Route path="/products" component={ProductList} />
<Route path="/products/:id" component={Product} />
<Route path="/products/admin" component={ProductsAdmin} />
```

users router (in users.jsx)

```
import UserList from "./user-list";
import User from "./user";

<Route path="/users" component={UserList} />
<Route path="/users/:id" component={User} />
```

You can then decide to lazy-load whole sections, or further split the bundles by lazy-loading deeper routes as well.